# Write a function called countdown that accepts a number as a parameter and every second decrements the value

Tags: javascript

My code should be counting down by 1 number and then returning 'done' when its finished. My code keeps resulting in Undefined and i'm not sure why.

```
function countDown(num){
    let count = setInterval(function () {
      num--;
      if(num <= 0) {
        clearInterval(count);
        return 'done';
      } else {
        return num;
      }
    }, 1000)
}
```

Comment: You didn't return anything from `countDown`

Comment: also, setInterval runs independently of any other code you have, so it has nowhere to "return to". It just runs, and at some point, stops. So you probably need to wrap this in a promise if you want to wait for it (asynchronously, of course) so you can do something else once it's done decrementing that value.

Comment: In any case: your function `countDown()` would only be able to return _one_ value. And a Promise can also only be resolved _once_. So, if you want a repeated action to take place, you will have to _do_ something with the values inside the `setInterval()` callback function instead of _returning_ them.

Comment: Could you provide more context to what you're trying to achieve? You may not need to use promises and the like depending on what the code actually needs to do.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question of why your function returns undefined, it's because all functions without a specific return value return undefined in JS.  In your case, all your function does is create a variable.

I'm not 100% sure what the parameters are in terms of whether you're expected to log the value or return the value. In the example below I logged the values.

I'd probably use `setTimeout` versus `setInterval`.  One way would be to recursively call the countDown function until done:

```js
function countDown(val) {
  console.log(val);
  // check if done
  if (val !== "done") {
    // if not set the next value 
    const next = val > 0 ? --val : "done";
    // call setTimeout with countDown passing the next value
    setTimeout(() => countDown(next), 1000);
  }
}

countDown(10);
```

As others pointed out function countDown() can only return one value.  You can yield multiple values with an async generator function though:

```js
async function* generator(num) {
  for (let i = num; i >= 0; i--) {
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));

    yield i;
  }
}

async function countDown(num) {
  const iterator = generator(num);
  for await (let value of iterator) {
    console.log(value);
  }
  console.log("done");
}

countDown(10)
```